# доступ к кнопкам через логическое поле АДМИН

Tags: c#, запрос, доступ, права-доступа

C#, Access DB.
Имеется главная форма программы со всем функционалом. Необходимо на данной форме проверить с помощью запроса SQL, является ли пользователь админом. Если нет - заблокировать кнопки.
таблица Пользователь включает в себя атрибуты: "Код пользователя", "Пароль", "Админ"(boolean).
Помогите написать запрос SELECT.

Comment: вопрос решен)))